# Why do I have multiple source directories under my azure-devops agent _work directory? How do I stop it happening?

Tags: linux, windows-10, azure-devops

I'm running an azure-devops agent on a self-hosted linux machine and I've recently started getting errors about running out of disk space, so I looked and found that the agent keeps **three full copies** of my code in its _work directory, plus what looks like 3 additional "smaller" versions:

```
2.1G    _work/8/s

27G     _work/4/s

420M    _work/2/s

25G     _work/6/s

2.1G    _work/9/s

25G     _work/7/s
```

What's the logic here - what few docs I found online talk about **a** working directory, why do I have so many working directories? Why are they so weirdly numbered (2,4,6,7,8,9)? And why the different sizes?

And, most importantly, how do I stop it from creating multiple versions?

Additional information: the pipeline runs with multi-configuration parallelism on this linux machine and another machine - a windows one. The windows machine also has what looks like multiple  copies, but its directories are numbered 1-5.

Comment: To run multiple jobs in parallel, multiple working directories are required, that’s kind of obvious. The jobs could modify their repositories so they cannot be shared.

Comment: The parallelism runs on multiple agents, not in the same agent. One job runs on agent A, another job on agent B. There are no two jobs on the same agent.

Comment: According to the "i" next to parallelism in classic ui:
`Multi-configuration: Run the same set of tasks on multiple configurations as specified in the multipliers. Configurations will run in parallel and each configuration will use a single agent. The total number of agents used by the job will depend on the number of configurations, and can be limited by specifying the maximum number of agents.`